# Знаки препинания при наличии двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

*Контекст:
Почему этот человек попал к нам в коллектив?*

**Ответ не заставляет себя ждать: промелькнувшее имя(,) и все встает на свои места.**

При такой структуре предложения запятая перед "и" ставится?

Comment: По-моему, смысл предложения не очень понятен. Но запятая здесь точно не понадобится. Если под ответом, "который не заставляет себя ждать", подразумевается "промелькнувшее имя", то лучше (на мой взгляд) вместо запятой поставить точку: _Ответ не заставляет себя ждать: промелькнувшее имя. И все встает на свои места_.

Comment: При ином понимании нужно будет тире: _Ответ не заставляет себя ждать. Промелькнувшее имя -- и все встает на свои места_. Но лучше всё-таки, по-моему, предложение как-то переработать.

Comment: Добавил контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

***Почему этот человек попал к нам в коллектив?***

***Ответ не заставляет себя ждать. Промелькнувшее имя —  и все встает на свои места.***

Comment: То есть,в том виде,который дан изначально,предложение написать нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая здесь, судя по всему, не нужна. Двоеточие здесь подставлено по мотивам того, что за ним идет предложение, раскрывающее смысл предыдущего. При такой трактовке получается что у нас два предложения с общей частью (той смысл которой раскрывается). Если бы смысл раскрывало только первое из двух предложений, для запятой были бы основания. Хотя в нашем случае очень трудно такое представить.

Но поскольку структура предложения без запятой зрительно не схватывается, и к тому же второе предложение (из тех что после двоеточия) противопоставляется первому, то напрашивается постановка тире (см. slava1947).

> То есть в том виде, который дан изначально, предложение написать нельзя?

Де-юре можно, без запятой. Но это не лучший выбор. И, если уж так ставить вопрос, то фраза сама по себе выглядит довольно корявой. А предложенный контекст только осложняет понимание.

Answer (score 0):

Можно оставить **запятую**, можно поставить **тире**:

Ответ не заставляет себя ждать: промелькнувшее имя, и все встает на свои места.

Ответ не заставляет себя ждать: промелькнувшее имя — и все встает на свои места.

Бессоюзная связь между простым предложением и ССП. Постановку тире можно связать с разной структурой предложений и резким переходом в ССП (если автор  подразумевает такой  переход). Непонятно, зачем нужно делить предложение н части.

Comment: На основании чего тут запятая? Если это ССП (то, что после двоеточия), то у его составляющих есть общая часть. Запятая возможна только если вы понимаете структуру иначе.

Comment: У Лопатина есть похожее предложение без запятой: Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится (Щерб.);  Но в нашем примере без паузы между второй и третьей частью предложение сложно понять, пауза нужна. Значит, формально надо ставить тире,  но кажется, что запятая тоже вполне справляется с этой задачей. Ведь если мы ставим тире, то эти части тоже никак не связываются в одну фразу, как положено при отсутствии запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна со Славой. Классический случай постановки тире в ССП.

Если первая часть сложносочиненного предложения или обе части являются односоставными номинативными предложениями (а у нас номинативное, т. е. назывное), между частями, как правило, ставится тире: Ещё напор — и враг бежит (П.); Ещё одна минута объяснения — и давнишняя вражда готова была погаснуть (Г.); Вот крик — и снова всё вокруг затихло (Л.).

[Тире в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135)