# Влияние уточнения на постановку запятой перед "и"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

**Говори как Саша: задача слишком сложная и ничего с этим не сделать.**

**Говори как Саша: задача слишком сложная и поэтому с этим ничего не сделать.**

*Уточнение:
В предложениях раскрывается смысл, а не цитируется речь.*

Как я понял, из-за наличия общей части **"Говори как Саша"**, запятая перед **"и"** не ставится.
Но при наличии **"поэтому"** во втором предложении, которое указывает на следствие, можно ли говорить о постановке запятой перед **"и"**, несмотря на общую часть? Или как-то по-другому можно расставить знаки препинания? Обособляется ли "поэтому"?

Вопрос возник из-за этой темы: [Знаки препинания при наличии двоеточия](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427994/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F)

В ней мнения разошлись, но мне кажется, что даже при наличии общей части с двоеточием мы можем ставить знаки препинания перед "и". Так как без них не получается передать смысловую нагрузку.

Comment: Мнения разошлись потому, что примеры ваши надуманные. Смысл не до конца понятен - отсюда и трактовки разные.

Comment: Смысл не до конца понятен - **отсюда и трактовки разные.** В какой-то степени это и есть ответ на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

1) **Запятая не ставится в обоих случаях**: Говори как Саша: задача слишком сложная и ничего с этим не сделать. Говори как Саша: задача слишком сложная и поэтому с этим ничего не сделать. Также: По словам Саши, задача слишком сложная и поэтому с этим ничего не сделать.

Отсутствие запятой говорит о том, что **оба предложения (а не одно) ― это мнение Саши.** Наречие "поэтому" является дополнительным структурным элементом, уточняющим отношения между двумя предложениями, связанными союзом И; на постановку запятой оно **не влияет**.

2) Ответ не заставляет себя ждать: промелькнувшее имя ― и все встает на свои места.

Здесь **отсутствие знаков (запятой или тире) невозможно,** так как при такой структуре  непонятен был бы смысл предложения. Поэтому можно предположить, что **не всегда два предложения можно объединить в одну фразу, что существуют исключения.** Обратим также внимание на то, что при наличии противительных союзов А, НО такое объединение невозможно. К примеру, тире скорее всего ставится в следующем предложении (при наличии **одиночного союза ИЛИ)**: Слышались крики: сдавайтесь ― или мы стреляем!

Comment: Почему нет запятой в *Говори, как Саша*?

Comment: Здесь паузы нет, ударением выделено только второе слово. Вообще-то это спорный момент, встречаются  выражения "говорит как политик. как теоретик, как поэт, как равный с равными", в которых запятая не ставится. От структуры предложения зависит, например: Он говорит, как отец.  Поэтому я оставила авторский вариант.

Comment: "Говорит как политик" -- это значит "говорит, будучи политиком" (см. пример из Розенталя "Я говорю как литератор"). Так что здесь (в Саше) запятая, безусловно, нужна, никакие "паузы" ни при чем, чистый сравнительный оборот.
Также нужна запятая и после "сложная": это обычное ССП.

Answer (score 2):

*Говори, как Саша: задача слишком сложная, и ничего с этим не сделать.*

Не одна, а две запятые нужны. Где здесь "уточнение"?!

*Говори, как Саша: задача слишком сложная, и поэтому с этим ничего не сделать.*

Абсолютно то же самое.

Answer (score 2):

Это не уточнение, а пояснение. Запятой действительно нет, потому что части сложносочинённого предложения объединены общим элементом - предложением, поясняемым двумя частями сложносочинённого предложения, предшествующим им и связанным с ними бессоюзной связью.

Говори, как Саша (а именно, например): задача слишком сложная и ничего с этим не сделать.

Во втором то же самое. Говори, как Саша: задача слишком сложная и поэтому с этим ничего не сделать. Оттенок следствия есть и в первом, и во втором предложениях, но лишь оттенок смысла, интонационно причинно-следственные отношения  здесь  не подчёркиваются.

В спорном предложении есть условия для постановки тире, а не запятой.Общность пояснения не отменяет отношения стремительности действий со значением следствия. Здесь без паузы вы не прочитаете.

Ответ не заставляет себя ждать (какой именно?): промелькнувшее имя - и все встает на свои места.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос, признаться. Почему то, что после запятой не прямая речь? Но даже если так, все равно не до конца понятна постановка.

Что могу сказать точно, запятая ни в первом, ни во втором случае запятая не нужна. То, что вторую часть можно рассматривать как следствие (не буду разбираться, так ли это) никак не сказывается на структуре предложения. Все равно после двоеточия идёт сложносочиненное предложение (с общей частью  - той, что после запятой). Вот если бы структура была иная: "с этим ничего не сделать и потому, что задача слишком сложная" - тут запятая была бы нужна, но не перед И.